# Can be displayed a vector-graphic image on a webpage?

Tags: html, svg

I have read about SVG object that are supported in some browsers. What about full vector-graphic images?

Comment: How do you define "full vector graphic images"?

Comment: What do you mean? Is SVG not a full vector-graphic image?

Comment: Hmmm , one day i used a javascript class to draw and display vectors for a GIS project in my university , i can share the code if you want .

Comment: What is a "full vector graphic image"? An .eps / .ps / .ai file?

Comment: CDR is *a vector format*, it's not more or less full than SVG. Since it's also proprietary, I don't think web browsers in general will handle it.

Comment: And how can I display it on a webpage? Has it any disadvantage to use vector-graphic instead of normal pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display a CorelDraw image on a web page, the web browser needs to understand the CDR image format. Since it is a complex, proprietary (not open) format, an out-of-the-box web browser will very likely not be able to understand it, hence not be able to display it.

If the user has a browser plugin installed that enables the browser to render the CDR format, it's possible. I do not know whether such a plugin exists though, and even if it does, don't count on any normal user having it installed.

SVG is an open standard for vector graphics that many browsers already support, so it's your best bet for displaying vector graphics in a browser. It's not supported across all browsers either though.

Comment: I found an example:http://www.normanfellows.com/images/item_2097-light-resizable.svg Is it possible to embed it into the page?

Comment: @user Please refer to http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML or various questions here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embed+svg+in+html

Comment: All major browser engines now support SVG natively, most have had this for years.

Comment: @Erik IE8- didn't support SVG at all, IE9 has *partial* SVG support. Since IE8- is still a sizable chunk of the browser market I wouldn't say that *all* browsers support it.

Comment: that's true, note that I wrote "all major browser engines" and not "all versions of all browsers on every possible platform". There's quite a difference.